# Proving simple inequality

Tags: inequalities

I have a simple function and want to make sure that it satisfies an inequality over a certain range of parameters.

My approach is:

```
In[125]:= a[x] := x^2

In[126]:= Reduce[a[x] > 0 && 1 <= x <= 2]

Out[126]= 1 <= x <= 2
```

However, I would expect an output of "True", since the inequality is satisfied over the entire range.

What do I need to invoke in order to obtain "True" as a result?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: `Reduce` solves the system of inequalities and returns the range of `x` in which the system is true. this code returns `True` `Refine[Reduce[a[x] > 0, x], 1 <= x <= 2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Reduce` is designed to reduce a set of inequalities to obtain the relevant information. In your case.

In:

```
Reduce[x^2 > 0 && 1 <= x <= 2]
```

Out:

```
1 <= x <= 2
```

tells you that your first inequality `x^2>0` was an obsolete infomation, for the set of inequalities. In other words this tells you, that the first equation is allways satisfied if the second equation is satisfied.

So its a problem of interpretation here.

If you want to have an explicit test, that yields `True` or `False`, you could simply use this:

```
satisfiesInequality[ineq_, range_] := 
Reduce[ineq && range] === Reduce[range]
```

another approach would be to integrate the `Boole`-Function over the range where you want to test the first inequation.

```
satisfiesInequality2[
ineq_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}] := (1 === 
Integrate[Boole[ineq], {x, xmin, xmax}]/(xmax - xmin))
```

add some `SyntaxInformation` that helps you using the function correctly:

```
SyntaxInformation[
satisfiesInequality2] = {"LocalVariables" -> {"Plot", {2, 
  Infinity}}, "ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, {_, _, _}}};
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's rephrase your problem:

> Show that $x^2 > 0$ ***for all*** $1\leq x\leq 2$.
>
> *or*
>
> $\forall_{x\in\left[1,2\right]}\;x^2>0$

Turns out Mathematica has a command for that, `ForAll`:

```
Reduce[ForAll[x, 1 <= x <= 2, x^2 > 0]]
(* True *)
```